# How can I change only a single option of a DependencyProperty's metadata in a subclass?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, measureoverride

We need to override a `DependencyProperty`'s metadata for our subclass.  Now I know that I can use `OverrideMetadata` and specify entirely new `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` object, but for the most part I want this new metadata to be exactly the same as the existing metadata except with one additional flag set (specifically `AffectsMeasure`)

My thought is to get the existing metadata, create a new metadata object, hand-copy all the members over from the old to the new (it doesn't support `Clone`) changing the one I want, then use the new one in the OverrideMetadata call.  But da** that is a lot of work for something otherwise so simple!

Am I missing something here?

### EDIT

First things first, I meant `AffectsMeasure` not `AffectsRender` (which I've changed above),

BUT... I just found out our class *already* has the `AffectsMeasure` flag set for the `Width` property.  The real issue is for containers of a `ListBox` (e.g. a `ListBoxItem`) the `MeasureOverride` is only called once, when first initialized.

Since this is technically an unrelated question, I'll start a new one and close this one.

Here's the link to the new question:

[Why is a ListBoxItem not calling MeasureOverride when its width is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7655632/168179)

Comment: Hi, what you could do as well is to call InvalidateVisual within your DP change value event handler, which to me is a cleaner way of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the metadata from the base class' metadata is definitely the way to go.  Though unfortunately the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` class doesn't expose the flags as they given, they are exposed as `bool` properties to indicate their state.  To get those values back as a `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions`, you'll have to go through the associated properties and read them back as one.

```
static DerivedClass()
{
    var oldMeta = (FrameworkPropertyMetadata)BaseClass.SomeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(BaseClass));
    var flags = GetFlags(oldMeta);

    // change the values as needed
    var meta = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        oldMeta.DefaultValue,
        flags,
        oldMeta.PropertyChangedCallback,
        oldMeta.CoerceValueCallback,
        oldMeta.IsAnimationProhibited,
        oldMeta.DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger
    );

    BaseClass.SomeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DerivedClass), meta);
}

static FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions GetFlags(FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata)
{
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions flags = FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None;
    if (metadata.AffectsArrange)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange;
    if (metadata.AffectsMeasure)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure;
    if (metadata.AffectsParentArrange)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange;
    if (metadata.AffectsParentMeasure)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure;
    if (metadata.AffectsRender)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender;
    if (metadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault;
    if (metadata.Inherits)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits;
    if (metadata.Journal)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal;
    if (metadata.IsNotDataBindable)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.NotDataBindable;
    if (metadata.OverridesInheritanceBehavior)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.OverridesInheritanceBehavior;
    if (metadata.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender)
        flags |= FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender;
    return flags;
}
```

Comment: Looking at the implementation of the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`, it maintains other state so cloning in general probably wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: It doesn't support 'Clone' anyway. BUT... turns out this isn't the issue.  I'm posting a new question related to what we're dealing with, which is a ListBoxItem that gets resized, but which doesn't internally call the MeasureOverride even though that flag is set for the Width property, and we don't know why.