# Why is a ListBoxItem not calling MeasureOverride when its width is changed?

Tags: wpf, layout, listboxitem, measureoverride, arrangeoverride

Ok, for illustrative purposes, below I created a subclass of `ListBoxItem` and a subclass of `ListBox` which uses it as its container by overriding both `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` and `GetContainerForItemOverride`.

Now when the window first appears, as expected, `MeasureOverride` is called on every `ListBoxItem` (with Infinity,Infinity) followed by `ArrangeOverride` being called on every item.

However, when resizing the `ListBox`, only `ArrangeOverride` is called on the `ListBoxItem`, not `MeasureOverride` even though the metadata for the width property is set to `AffectsMeasure`.

> NotE: I know I can get around this by setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollbarVisibility` to 'Disabled' in which case `MeasureOverride` does get called as expected because that scroll setting forces the items to match the width of the listbox and thus naturally would re-fire.  However, I'm still trying to figure out why Measure isn't called by default anyway because the metadata for the `Width` property has the `AffectsMeasure` flag set and the width is changing via the `ArrangeOverride` step.

Is that flag just a hint for its container and in the case of a control placed in a `ScrollViewer` it's ignored?  My guess is that unless you disable the scrolling, the controls have an infinite area available to them, so once they are measured, there's no need to re-measure them again.  Disable the horizontal scrolling however and you're stating the width isn't unlimited, hence the `MeasureOverride` is called again.  But that's just a guess, albeit a logical one.

Here's example code to play with. Create a new WPF project and paste this in the window's CodeBehind and look at the debug output.  Next, set the HorizontalScrollbarVisibility flag and you'll see that it does get called.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(){
        InitializeComponent();
        var items = new List<object>(){ "This is a really, really, really, really long sentence"};
        var lbx = new ListBoxEx { ItemsSource = items };
        this.Content = lbx;
    }

}

public class ListBoxEx : ListBox
{
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item){
        return (item is ListBoxItemEx);
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride(){
        return new ListBoxItemEx();
    }
}

public class ListBoxItemEx : ListBoxItem
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize){
        Console.WriteLine("MeasureOverride called with " + availableSize);
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize){
        Console.WriteLine("ArrangeOverride called with " + finalSize);
        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the answer is it's not firing because the Measure pass is affecting the panel, not the items, and the panel itself hasn't resized so there's no reason to re-measure its children.

However, when setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollbarVisibility` to `Disabled`, the width of the panel tracks the width of the ListBox, not its contents, therefore the children do need to be re-measured, hence that's why they were in that case.